# Wordpress Multisite with multiple domains and redirects with one .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wordpress

We run a Wordpress Multisite installation with a about 15 different websites all on their own domain. On one of those sites we want to migrate to a new theme that uses custom post types and migrate some of the content to these new custom post types. Because of this migration some links will break, usually this is easily solvable with a 301 redirect in .htaccess.

The nature of a multisite install just gives us a single .htaccess and when I create a simple redirect like this:

Redirect 301 /testredirect http://www.testredirect.com

Every single domain will redirect this link to testdirect.com and not just the one we just migrated. Can we fix this in this single .htaccess or is there some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved our troubles using the redirection plug-in for wordpress and some regular expressions: https://www.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would probably be a switch to Mod_Rewrite, as you can add conditions (RewriteCond ....) to each redirection rule eg.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.testredirect.com
RewriteRule /testredirect  /  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I'm no expert with .htaccess, so I've tried this:

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.thisdomain.com
    RewriteRule /redirectthis  /tothis  [R=301,L]

And that didn't work (and now I don't know why the formatting doesn't work.)

Comment: Have a read of: [URL Aliasing, Redirection, Rewriting and Reverse Proxying using Apache HTTPD](http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/4043/URL-Aliasing-Redirection-Rewriting-and-Reverse-Proxying-using-Apache-HTTPD.html)